# 1000 iptables entries on CentOS?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I just got a new dedicated server with CentOS and I'm trying to debug some network problems. In doing so, I found *over one thousand* iptables entries. Is this the default on a CentOS system? Is there some firewall package that might be guilty of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the default on a CentOS
>   system?

No. The default one is below.

> Is there some firewall package that
>   might be guilty of doing that?

Probably. You don't say what the entries are but if they're banning CIDR blocks I'd guess your server has a firewall like [APF](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) or [CSF](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html) that can subscribe to blacklist like [Spamhaus' DROP](http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/) and that is how your rules are being generated. Alternatively, there might be some cron job which does it all. If you do a `grep -rl iptables /etc/*` that will tell you all the files that mention iptables and hopefully track down what is generating your entries.

Here's the default iptables from /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks. APF is at least part of the problem. I had over 500 lines mention iptables in 50 files. `iptables` has been made completely useless by this thing.

Comment: Okay, I found the original problem; it was indeed APF. APF made `iptables` completely unusable, but APF itself was configurable via `/etc/apf/conf.apf`.